# Exporting data from phonegap app into XLS as an email attachment into email compose

Tags: php, ajax, cordova, phpexcel

Is there any example around or can someone provide an example whereby I could do the following in phonegap?

My app brings in queried data via AJAX from our server.
I would then like the user to export the results to an Excel spreadheet which is attached to an email (XLS attachment) for composing.

I can do this in PHP no problem using the library PHPExcel (http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/), but seeing as though Phonegap doesn't compile with PHP I'm wondering if there is any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap can run only JavaScript. So one easy way is to create a CSV file using your data and create a file with .xls extension. It will easily open up as an excel file.

Comment: Thank you. Yep I'm aware it can run JS only, but I'm looking for an example method used to do something like this, even if it is a JS example. Thank you!